# Nullable object must have a value, Linq to SQL, MVC issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I've taken over a project for a developer who has left the company and am not overly familiar with MVC.  When running the program I get the error that "Nullable object must have a value".

One of the cells in a table is populated by the following:

```
<td>@SRA_Acquire.Models.Auth.Users.GetUserNameById((int)issue.UserID)</td>
```

Which is populated by the following:

```
public static string GetUserNameById(int userId)
{
    return GetUserById(userId).Name;
}

internal static UserProfile GetUserById(int userId)
{
    var db = new UsersContext();
    return db.UserProfiles.Where(c => c.UserId == userId).Single();
}
```

When stepping through the code the userId is correct, but I get errors stating that `c.UserID does not exist in the current context`

However in my `AccountModels.cs` it shows

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("AuthContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UsersInRoles> UsersInRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Roles> Roles { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserProfile", Schema = "dbo")]
public class UserProfile 
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool IsLockedOut { get; set; }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Doesn't this look like `LINQ to SQL` not `Entity Framework`?

Comment: From your error message seems like you have not updated DB with the latest changes cos you have `UserId` property in your class, but an error message shows that there is no `UserID` in context.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update `c.UserId == userId` condition so that you'll avoid such error:

```
c => c.UserId != null && c.UserId == userId
```

Comment: Turns out that there was indeed a null value buried within the result set.  With the following addition of code I was able to over ride any null values and populate text that allowed me to continue looping through the rest of the data


        public static string GetUserNameById(int? userId)
        {
            if (userId != null)
            {
                string Name = GetUserById((int)userId).Name;
                return Name;
            }
            else return "user did not save form before suspending";
        }